# using MapBubble in country Chart in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

So I have is a dummy data of Indian Country Map. For example, I am using the Highchart's Indian Map Dummy Data.

```
// Create the chart
Highcharts.mapChart('container', {
  chart: {
    map: 'countries/in/in-all'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Highmaps basic demo'
  },
  subtitle: {
    text: 'Source map: <a href="http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/countries/in/in-all.js">India</a>'
  },
  mapNavigation: {
    enabled: true,
    buttonOptions: {
      verticalAlign: 'bottom'
    }
  },
  colorAxis: {
    min: 0
  },
  series: [{
    type: 'mapbubble', // This I added
    data: data,
    name: 'Random data',
    states: {
      hover: {
        color: '#BADA55'
      }
    },
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      format: '{point.name}'
    }
  }]
});
```

This is the example I am using : https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.11.0/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/mapdata/countries/in/in-all

But When I am trying to Channge the Chart to MapBubble Type . The Chart is getting Vanished :

Like in the link below

https://jsfiddle.net/abnitchauhan/tdk7a8ex/

I Want the Chart to have mapBubble. but its throwing an error.

Any Help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need another series for map data and a data in the bubble series with `z` values:

```
    series: [{
        name: 'Countries',
        color: '#E0E0E0',
        enableMouseTracking: false
    }, {
        type: 'mapbubble',
        keys: ['hc-key', 'z'],
        joinBy: ['hc-key'],
        data: data,
        ...
    }]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/wj7rzq2p/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/series.mapbubble.data

Comment: hi there @ppotaczek. I knew you will come to the rescue. That's exactly I needed. Really really appreciated. Thanks